# Spring Batch find starting job executions

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application with one job. Job executions order is critical to me, so `JobLauncher` configured as a single thread job pool. In other words if few executions were triggered, one execution will be running, and other gonna wait in the queue.

Job executions table will look like that:

```
        ╒═════╤═════════════════════╤════════════╤════════════╤═════╕
        │ ... │ START_TIME          │ END_TIME   │ STATUS     │ ... │
        ╞═════╪═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════╡
        │ ... │ 2019-07-11 11:03:08 │ NULL       │ STARTED    │ ... │
        ├─────┼─────────────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────┤
        │ ... │ NULL                │ NULL       │ STARTING   │ ... │
        └─────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────┘
```

If JVM crashes, I need to recover from that state and do some audit, so I need to find all `STARTED` and `STARTING` executions.

Find the first one is not a problem, I can do it with `JobExplorer`:

```java
Set<JobExecution> executions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("jobName");
```

It will give me only `STARTED` execution with present `START_TIME`. But how to find all `STARTING` executions?

The only way I've found so far is to iterate over the job instances, then find `STARTING` execution for every instance. Something like this:

```java
        jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName("jobName", 0, 100)
                .forEach(jobInstance -> {
                    jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance)
                            .stream()
                            .filter(execution -> STARTING.equals(execution.getStatus()))
                            .forEach(execution -> {
                                // do the job
                            });
                });
```

The problem here that you always doing a full scan with a limit (I specified 100). Are there any better way like `jobExplorer.findStartingJobExecutions("jobName")` in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 1):

I see no public APIs to get a job execution by status. What you can do is (in pseudo code):

```
JobInstance jobInstance = jobInstanceDao.getJobInstance(jobName, jobParameters);
List<JobExecution> jobExecutions =  jobExplorer.findJobExecutions(jobInstance);
// iterate over job execution and filter by status
```

This will avoid loading all job instances (one hundred at a time).

That said, I think the `JobRepository` interface could add a method to get a job instance by name and parameters (similar to `isJobInstanceExists`) to avoid using the `jobInstanceDao` as shown in my previous snippet.

**EDIT:**

I guess your initial requirement is to mark a job execution as failed to be able to restart it. For this, you can manually change the status of job execution (as well as its step executions) to `FAILED` and set its `END_TIME` to a non null value (This is explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job). With that, you will be able to restart failed executions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have `jobParameters` on start of application. Can I get them somehow only for `STARTING` jobs? There could be a number of them.

Comment: Not with the provided APIs, but you can always do it yourself with a `jdbcTemplate` for example. I edited the answer with more details about what to do to be able to restart a job execution.

Comment: Thank you for response, but the main problem for me is to find a job executions with status `STARTING`, and I can have several job instances with such job executions. I don't want to write my own JDBC query for that, and support it afterwards. So I'm looking for some ways to do it with Batch API.

Comment: As I mentioned, Batch APIs do not provide a way to get a job execution by status. But my question to you: why do you need to get job executions with status `STARTING` at first place? I think we are facing the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) here and I'm trying to help you solve your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I mentioned in the question that my problem is to restore and audit my queue of job executions after JVM crash. And I posted the solution I've found, and it works. But posted solution is more a workaround, and I'm looking for a better one. But I don't see how your suggestion with `jobInstanceDao` could help me.